# Why do requests for host A fall into the virtual server for host B with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, vhosts

I have a Nextcloud and a Collabora instance running on a SBC.
Also on that SBC, there is an Nginx that terminates SSL for both services using a single Let's Encrypt certificate for multiple domains.

Recently, I've noticed that it's no longer possible to access Collabora through Nextcloud. I don't use office documents very often so I can't say when it stopped working but I'm fairly sure there were no changes to the Nginx config (it is versioned using git).
In the browser console it says: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`.
That appears to be because the request for Collabora is redirected to the Nextcloud backend.

There are two log files, one for office.redacted.com and one for cloud.redacted.com. A `log_format` called `main` logs the hostname from the request.
On the last line, there's a request to the office host in the log file for the cloud vhost:

```
# tail -f /var/log/nginx/nextcloud.log
clientIP6_A - - [10/Mar/2023:09:59:06 +0100]  207 "cloud.redacted.com" "PROPFIND /remote.php/dav/files/user/tmp/some.docx HTTP/2.0" 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
clientIP6_A - - [10/Mar/2023:09:59:07 +0100]  200 "cloud.redacted.com" "GET /apps/richdocuments/index?fileId=65827&requesttoken=yPfTctIra8puYF%2BTcNKf6YxKLomzuKtuq%2FIicCSCAIE%3D%3AgcCGRrpmU4UrMwzbHYLzvv1lW9%2FJ9Z1FmsBzM3DkY7c%3D&path=%2Ftmp%2Fsome.docx HTTP/2.0" 9093 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
clientIP6_A - - [10/Mar/2023:09:59:08 +0100]  400 "office.redacted.com" "POST /browser/ef89c82b3/cool.html?WOPISrc=https%3A%2F%2Fcloud.redacted.com%2Findex.php%2Fapps%2Frichdocuments%2Fwopi%2Ffiles%2F65827_ocrto4zmrcr9&title=some.docx&lang=en&closebutton=1&revisionhistory=1 HTTP/2.0" 17024 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Here is an excerpt of the Nginx config:

```
upstream collabora {
  server localhost:9980;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name office.redacted.com;

  ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud/privkey.pem;

..
}

upstream nc {
  server localhost:8123;
}

server {
  listen 443      ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  listen 12;
  listen [::]:12;
  server_name cloud.redacted.com;

  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nextcloud/privkey.pem;

..
}
```

It looks as if the virtual host is working, though:

```
# tail /var/log/nginx/office.log 
clientIP4_A - - [10/Mar/2023:10:21:12 +0100]  200 "office.redacted.com" "GET /hosting/capabilities HTTP/1.1" 324 "-" "Nextcloud Server Crawler" "-"
clientIP4_A - - [10/Mar/2023:10:22:13 +0100]  200 "office.redacted.com" "GET /hosting/capabilities HTTP/1.1" 324 "-" "Nextcloud Server Crawler" "-"
...
```

Why is the request for one vhost handled by the other?
Is this a bug, maybe a problem with connection re-use, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I lay a trap for myself... Copy'n'paste from the Collabora wiki without paying attention.
The log entries gave it away: IPv4 arrived at Collabora, IPv6 did not.

The issue was a missing `listen [::]:443 ssl;` in the Collabora vhost:

```
  listen      443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl; # added this
```

If only `listen 443` could be expected to be dual-stack :-D